# C++ Library for XML-RPC

Tags: c++, xml-rpc

There is a list of C++ XMLRPC implementations in Wikipedia:

- [Libiqxmlrpc](http://libiqxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/)
- [Ultra lightweight XML-RPC library for C++](http://ulxmlrpcpp.sourceforge.net/)
- [XML-RPC for C and C++](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/)
- [XmlRpc++](http://xmlrpcpp.sourceforge.net/)
- [XmlRpc C++ client for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlrpcc4win/)
- [gSOAP toolkit for C and C++ supporting XML-RPC and more](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html)
- [libmaia: XML-RPC for Qt/C++](http://wiedi.frubar.net/blog/2008/03/08/libmaia-xml-rpc-with-qt4/)

I wonder that people use which of these libraries most. Do you have experience with these libraries?

Answer (score 2):

I've used gSOAP in the past. I found it pretty nice to work with. It's fairly mature and runs on a variety of platforms. I thought the documentation, along with examples to be sufficient. We used it on a project that needed to communicate with ASP.NET web services from a Linux environment.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I will use XML-RPC just for communicating a server application in the same LAN. gSOAP will be a big solution for this purpose, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `xmlrpc++` is what you're looking for. Though I can't give objective comparison to every library listed here, I must say that's it's extremely versatile, well-written and somewhat easy to get used to.

Well, it actually some kind of lacks in documentation, but this is also subjective (hate this doxygenized way of presenting information).

**Added :** `ulxmlrpcpp` also (never used it, just looked through documentation) seems fine and well-designed.

Comment: Having xmlrpc++ in a project I found it has lots of problems that are not obvious but come with intensive usage. Also Strings are note automatically escaped etc. I would suggest using another implementation that is not abandoned since 2003